# I can't type symbols such as @ and $ into my flash textbox

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs5

I have an input text field for email address that is not allowing me to type anything but letters, numbers, spaces, and * I need to be able to type @ as this is an email address input field... Is there a setting I can change to allow for this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you making sure to embed those characters in your input textbox? This will make all characters that you specify available in your exported Flash movie. Follow these steps:

1. Make sure that your textfield is set to be Input Text (which it sounds like it is)
2. Under the Character palette in the Properties palette (CS4 and up), click on Character Encoding. If you are using CS3 and below look in the Properties palette and there should be a similar option for embedding characters
3. In the dialog you should probably select Uppercase, Lowercase, Numerals, and Punctuation
4. Click Ok

Doing this will tell Flash that, when you publish your SWF, you need it to also include the font set for your input field. 
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're embedding the required glyphs in your text field.

Select the text field, hit properties and select embed, then make sure the window that appears ends up looking like this or similar:

[image]

It's worth a mention that your font must also support those characters.